# how to find which port reverse connection wants to connect?

Tags: windows-10, port-forwarding, port, reverse-proxy, reverse-tunnel

A Client wants to connect to a server.

The server doesn't know which port the client is using for open that port.

How to find which port reverse connection (incoming connection) wants to connect?

Answer (score 1):

When the client connects to the server, 4 pieces of information are sent with the initial request - the source and destination IP, but also the source and destination port.

Thus, if provided with full connectivity, the server will know the port to connect back to because its associated with the from address.

Where this is not known in advance, it would be necessary to either define a range of from ports in the client (if allowed by the protocol), or for the router to accept traffic from all ports with the appropriate destination port (or use connection tracking to if the ports are related) and forward them on as appropriate.

Comment: Is there any specific tool can do that job?

Comment: You need to better define the question to get a better answer - the problem - if you have one - could be the router - in which case a tool won't help - but you can use any packet sniffer.   Wireshark is commonly used.